# Laravel 5.4 post route returns no response

Tags: laravel

I can't get even a simple a Laravel post route to return anything. If I switch to get it works fine. Chrome network tab shows the request is a 200 code, but the response is empty even if I dd() something.

```
Route::post("/login", function(){
    dd("test");
});
```

Also the request is definitely reaching the route correctly, as I can write a file (file_put_contents), but I can't get any return from the post route, whether is a return response()->json(), dd(), var_dump, or just echo.

Comment: Are you trying to do a `get` or `post` request?

Comment: I want to do a post request.

Comment: Have you tried `curl` or `postman`? It seems to be simple, no reason to have problems there.

Comment: check first `storage/logs`, also try with postman and curl by sending in the header `Content-Type` and `Accept` attribute with the proper values `text/html` or `application/json` if using html or json, sometimes it happens to have a blank page when no `Content-Type` and `Accept` is specified

Comment: Have you set permissions on your `storage` folder properly? Might not be able to write to `storage/framework` or `storage/logs`

Comment: Postman returns correctly... so I guess its not Laravel. I think this seems to be a CORS issue...

Comment: Yes, it was a CORS issue. My CORS middleware was not applied to the route! Thanks for help guys.